# Is there a processor to convert prometheus data types?

Tags: prometheus, counter, metrics, open-telemetry, gauge

I admit this may be a bit of a stupid question, however, we're in a bit of a pickle. Essentially, we have a paid web-based application that hosts (what they claim to be) prometheus metrics. There are two metrics that are measuring the number of objects stored in the application database. OpenMetrics principles indicate that this should be a Gauge but the application developers chose to report them as Counters instead. The problem is that, when ingesting these metrics, the values are being recorded as zeroes because our Observability solution treats all counters as deltas (e.g., they don't support cummulative counters). As such, we're in a position where we aren't able to accurately measure these metrics because of downfalls with two different pieces of software that we can't control.

So the question is, does a processor exist that will let us change the type of our metric from Counter to Gauge?

I've found examples for converting numeric data types and changing labels, metric names, etc. but nothing regarding changing the actual metric type.

Comment: One challenge that you face is in determining the definitive value. If there were some proxy for this value that receives a counter of additions (and presumably a counter of deletions) and applies them for you, it would have to start at a definitive value and you'd be challenged to ensure it doesn't miss adds|deletes unless you can perform a reconciliation. If you can perform a reconciliation (i.e. always determine the true value), you should use that as your source and expose it as a metric.

Comment: I suspect (!?) that the provider doesn't want to expose the value as a metric because it's difficult|expensive to do this whereas it's relatively easy to emit an event every time something is added or deleted.